# How to load new data to Flatlist in both "Up" and "Down" ways onEndReached in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flatlist with React Native for Android where I need to dynamically load new data when reached end of Flatlist in both "Up" and "Down" position of Flatlist (or "Left" and "Right" in horizontal view).

However Flatlist has only native function to do something in onEndReached in "Down" position (or "Right" in horizontal).

You can workaround with detecting if user scrolls left or right, but when I append new data to state to "Up" position so they are pushed in the beggining of the array, Flatlist is bugged and doesn't scroll like when you append new data to the end of the array.

Although it loads new data to array, view is glitched and not scrolling.

Now I am just pushing data to the begining of the array like this:

```
this.setState({
  data: [
    ...newData,
    ...this.state.data
  ]
})
```

TLDR: Is there any way how to append new data to array in state to the begging of array, so scrolling feels natural and view is not glitched due to changing positions in state/index?

Comment: pull to refresh might help you, `onRefresh` and `refreshing` are props which will help you to make this working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at react-waypoint.

https://github.com/civiccc/react-waypoint

You can put a  at the top and one at the bottom and deal each appropriately.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).